# OpenCV connection ps3 eye camera (python)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, connection, virtual-reality

### Heading I need to get an image at the same time (almost, it is possible to take turns in a loop) from two PS3 Eye cameras, and then work with them using OpenCV.

We need drivers for the ps3 eye multicam (for example, these are not suitable https://codelaboratories.com/downloads/)

As an option for drivers there is a program *zadig*(https://zadig.akeo.ie/), and in particular WinUSB (libusb), but OpenCV Python (the standard function cv2.VideoCapture) sees only one camera. I found a project that can use several cameras at once in OpenCV with WinUSB drivers (libusb) - https://github.com/psmoveservice/PSMoveService/releases (Open bin/test_camera.exe). But it is written in C++ and due to its incompetence in this programming language, I could not port the code to python.

In the end, I need drivers and Python code to use the ps3 eye multicam in OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking this. Get the environment you want to build.

https://github.com/bensondaled/pseyepy

Let's you configure the camera as well.